# Python iterate through columns in a .csv

Tags: pandas

How can I iterate through columns in a .csv of varying col numbers, performing calculations on the data? Here is what I have, the problem is that I really don't know where to start with this so I haven't tried much and Googling hasn't helped.

```
import pandas as pd
file = r'C:\Users\cmcgrath\...'

loopdata = pd.read_csv(file)
loopdata = pd.DataFrame(loopdata)
loopdata.index = loopdata['index']

for col in loopdata where i :
    print(loopdata.iloc[1])
```

I have some more complicated code that I wrote for another project, but it doesn't work much better than excel because I have to manually update it if I add or delete columns. Once I figure out how to work with something more basic, then i can scale that to more complicated logic.

A) how can I loop thorough the cols and created a new data frame where each row is the percent change between a cell and the cell below it?

B) how can i write the code so in the event that the data frame has a varying number of rows

Thanks,

Charlie

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on guidance of asking a good question.  Specifically, what have you tried already?  Post code of your current attempt.  What input are you using?  What output do you get?  And what output are you trying to get?

Comment: I updated my original question with some more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.diff()` function. This gives the percentage change of value of a row as compared to next row for every column:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,5,9,14,15,16], 'col2':[2,22,33,54,66,77]})
    df.apply(lambda x: x.diff() / x)

      col1       col2
0      NaN        NaN
1   0.800000    0.909091
2   0.444444    0.333333
3   0.357143    0.388889
4   0.066667    0.181818
5   0.062500    0.142857
```